# Procedurally create a dynamic object for Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net, dapper

I've seen many posts about creating `ExpandoObject` objects and such, but it does not work in my case. I need to create an object like

```
var someObj = new {
    term1 = "someValue",
    term2 = "other",
    ...
};
```

Basically, we are using [`Dapper`](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and we need to create a query dynamically, where the `WHERE` clause is fabricated from a given array of arguments. We are **not** generalizing queries! It's a single method receiving a variable number of arguments and we need to check `OR` each value on a single column.

Right now, the only viable solution is to revert and directly use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, or is there any way to make this work?

**Update:**

This is what most likely *should* work, but doesn't :

```
string inWhere = null;
dynamic inTerms = new ExpandoObject();
IDictionary<string, object> inTermsDict = inTerms;

if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Term) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Term))) {
    inWhere = "(" + string.Join(" OR ", filter.Terms.Select((t, i) => "{0} LIKE @p" + i)) + ")";
    int termIndex = 0;
    foreach (string term in filter.Terms) {
        inTermsDict.Add("p" + (termIndex++), term);
    }
}

// ...

var rows = db.Query("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE {baseCondition}" +
     (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inWhere) ? "" : string.Format(" AND " + inWhere, "columnName")),
     inTerms as object);
```

Comment: Do you mean `ExpandoObject`? Please write how are you going to call that procedure, because I didn't saw anything procedural in your examples.

Comment: Very well, I'm adding more info...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, as we found the proper solution earlier today.

Simply put, we found the [`IDynamicParameters`](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#33) And this class simply solves everything, acting as a `Dictionary`.

```
var inTerms = new Dapper.DynamicParameters();

inTerms.Add("@p" + (termIndex++), somveValue);
```

Everyone's happy!

Comment: For info, you can mix and match approaches here; you can also *initialize* the `DynamicParameters` with a regular object, then add any additional properties you need. Meaning: you don't need to manually add *every* property

Comment: Thanks for the info. The object passed to the constructor would, then, act as base parameters as I understand. We haven't needed this feature so far, but it's good to know.

Comment: This has allowed me to use Dapper on a hosting plan with Medium trust, as it seems that using an anonymous object for parameters requires Reflection.Emit which is not allowed on Medium trust.